# Seeking ship manifests 1903-1912 from Spain to Philippines

Tags: 1910s, manifest, 1900s-decade, spain, philippines

I am looking for ship manifests 1903 - 1912 from Spain to Philippines, possibly Iloilo. My search is for Jose G. Paramos and wife Tamanan

I have done online searches, Ancestry, Newspapers and Church of Latter Day Saint's. I do know that the Paramos's had a daughter, born in Iloilo and she was married there in 1925.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.culturaydeporte.gob.es/cultura/areas/archivos/mc/archivos/agi/portada.html

http://pares.culturaydeporte.gob.es/inicio.html

I will try to do a search myself, see what i can find.

https://1898.mforos.com/1035039/9476407-las-rutas-entre-espana-y-manila-caminos-comerciales-en-expansion/

The companies that covered the line The lines of communication by sea in 1896 were the Trasatlántica Company, which held the contract for correspondence, official passage and the transfer of troops. Also included were the Compañía de Pinillos and the Compañía de Izquierdo, which every four weeks left Liverpool, Santander, Cádiz and Barcelona for Suez, Aden, Colombo, Singapore, Manila and Ilo-Ilo; and the French Maritime Couriers, a fortnightly service of mail steamers from Havre, Bordeaux, and Marseilles to Egypt, India, Cochinchina, Tonkin, Siam, Manila, China, Japan, and Australia.